# ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_996 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I got the below code:

```
# prepare each input head
in_layers = list()
em_layers = list()
for i in range(len(X_train_enc_list)):
    # calculate the number of unique inputs
    n_labels = len(unique(X_train_enc_list[i]))
    print(f'n_labels ==> {n_labels}')
    # define input layer
    in_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
    print(f'1) {in_layer}')
    # define embedding layer
    em_layer = Embedding(n_labels, 10)(in_layer)
    print(f'2) {em_layer}')
    em_layer = Flatten()(em_layer)
    print(f'3) {em_layer}\n')
    # store layers
    in_layers.append(in_layer)
    em_layers.append(em_layer)
    
# concat all embeddings
merge = Concatenate()(em_layers)
output = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_dim=50)(merge)
model = Model(inputs=in_layers, outputs=output)

input_free_text = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Embedding(vocab_size, 64)(input_free_text)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
model_free_text = Model(inputs=input_free_text, outputs=x)

all_models = [model_free_text, model]
evaluate_list = [X_test_tokenized] + X_test_enc_list
model_inputs = [X_train_tokenized] + X_train_enc_list
combined = Concatenate()([m.output for m in all_models])

z = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(combined)
model = Model(inputs=[model_free_text.input, model.input], outputs=z)


model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

history = model.fit(x=model_inputs, y=y_train_enc, class_weight=class_weights_dict, 
                    validation_data=([X_test_tokenized, X_test_ord], y_test_enc), 
                    batch_size=128, epochs=20)
```

and the last line raises this exception:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1000 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 50 but received input with shape (None, 650)

Now I'm kinda understand where the numbers are coming from - from the for loop iteration.
This is why I've added the print inside:

```
2
2
2
50
9
```

Here's the full trace:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-310-da42e830ac2b> in <module>
     64 # model.summary()
     65 # keras.utils.plot_model(model, "model.png", show_shapes=True)
---> 66 history = model.fit(x=model_inputs, y=y_train_enc, class_weight=class_weights_dict, 
     67                     validation_data=([X_test_tokenized, X_test_ord], y_test_enc),
     68                     batch_size=128, epochs=20)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1212                 model=self,
   1213                 steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
-> 1214           val_logs = self.evaluate(
   1215               x=val_x,
   1216               y=val_y,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, return_dict, **kwargs)
   1487             with trace.Trace('test', step_num=step, _r=1):
   1488               callbacks.on_test_batch_begin(step)
-> 1489               tmp_logs = self.test_function(iterator)
   1490               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1491                 context.async_wait()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    761     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    762     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 763         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    764             *args, **kwds))
    765 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3048       args, kwargs = None, None
   3049     with self._lock:
-> 3050       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3051     return graph_function
   3052 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3277     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3278     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3279         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3280             self._name,
   3281             self._python_function,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1323 test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1314 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1307 run_step  **
        outputs = model.test_step(data)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1266 test_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=False)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1030 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:420 call
        return self._run_internal_graph(
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:556 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1013 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:251 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1034 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 50 but received input with shape (None, 650)
```

So I guess the error indicates that the model expects input shape of 50: `10 * number of iterations` (10 comes from the `Embedding` layer) and it gets 650 because `10*(2+2+2+50+9)=650`, but I don't get why. Can someone please explain that to me?

**Updated with the debug info output:**

```
n_labels ==> 2
1) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1032'), name='input_1032', description="created by layer 'input_1032'")
2) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='embedding_996/embedding_lookup/Identity_1:0', description="created by layer 'embedding_996'")
3) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='flatten_606/Reshape:0', description="created by layer 'flatten_606'")

n_labels ==> 2
1) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1033'), name='input_1033', description="created by layer 'input_1033'")
2) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='embedding_997/embedding_lookup/Identity_1:0', description="created by layer 'embedding_997'")
3) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='flatten_607/Reshape:0', description="created by layer 'flatten_607'")

n_labels ==> 2
1) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1034'), name='input_1034', description="created by layer 'input_1034'")
2) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='embedding_998/embedding_lookup/Identity_1:0', description="created by layer 'embedding_998'")
3) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='flatten_608/Reshape:0', description="created by layer 'flatten_608'")

n_labels ==> 50
1) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1035'), name='input_1035', description="created by layer 'input_1035'")
2) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='embedding_999/embedding_lookup/Identity_1:0', description="created by layer 'embedding_999'")
3) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='flatten_609/Reshape:0', description="created by layer 'flatten_609'")

n_labels ==> 9
1) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1036'), name='input_1036', description="created by layer 'input_1036'")
2) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='embedding_1000/embedding_lookup/Identity_1:0', description="created by layer 'embedding_1000'")
3) KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='flatten_610/Reshape:0', description="created by layer 'flatten_610'")

[(11652, 128), (11652, 1), (11652, 1), (11652, 1), (11652, 1), (11652, 1)]
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could add more `print()` to see what you have in other variables - maybe it will show what is wrong.

Comment: @furas I've already printed whatever I thought could be useful. If you wish, I can add more - just let me know where exactly

Comment: I would print all variable and information which part of code is executed - it needs many `print()` but at least it shows exactly what code is doing. Sometimes it use wrong values in variables which we couldn't expect.  It could be simpler if you could create minimal working code with some data directly in code - they can be generated randomly - so we could simply copy and run it - to see problem and test ideas for solution.

Comment: @furas updated the question with much more verbosity (added prints to the for loop)

Comment: Add a extra dimension to your input X_train as a batch_size =1. Thanks!